# apt update not working after adding folder to apt cache

Tags: apt, updates, ibm

Ubuntu version: ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64

Hi, I am trying to setup and install ubuntu ibm mq server and I followed this setup guide:
[ibm mq ubuntu setup guide](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu/)
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-ubuntu/

I managed to follow until steps 3, I have extracted the tar file and there's an MQServer folder in /home/alex/ with all the .ded files inside but after I created the .list file with the following into /etc/apt/sources.list.d

> deb [trusted=yes] file:/home/alex/MQServer ./

and run sudo apt update, I encountered the following error and I am not sure why

```
Get:4 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Translation-en_US
Ign:4 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Translation-en_US
Get:3 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Packages
Ign:3 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Packages
Get:5 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Translation-en
Ign:5 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Translation-en
Get:3 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Packages
Err:3 file:/home/alex/MQServer ./ Packages
  File not found - /home/alex/MQServer/./Packages (2: No such file or directory)
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [751 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [134 kB]
Fetched 1,222 kB in 3s (356 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/alex/MQServer/./InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch file:/home/alex/MQServer/./Packages  File not found - /home/alex/MQServer/./Packages (2: No such file or directory)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```